# Converting excel data from repeating rows to non-repeating columns

Tags: vba, excel

I need to convert the following row-column format. Where the Name is repeated with various values.

```
Name Value
XYZ   1
XYZ   2
XYZ   3
XYZ   4
XYZ   5
XYZ   6
XYZ   7
ABC   7
ABC   6
ABC   5
ABC   4
ABC   3
ABC   2
ABC   1
```

I need to convert into this type of a format.

```
XYZ ABC
1   7
2   6
3   5
4   4
5   3
6   2
7   1
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What code have you tried to use so far?

Comment: Put `XYZ` and `ABC` in their respective columns.  The in the First cell under `XYZ` put `=INDEX($B:$B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$2:$B$15)/($A$2:$A$15=D$1),ROW(1:1)))` copy over one column and down 7 rows.

Comment: @ScottCraner Than you for the response. I'm getting an error with this formula.

Comment: @Rdster I'm not a programmer. I just don't know how to do it period.

Comment: Comments sometimes adds non printable characters.  Type it in instead of copying.

Comment: Same problem... :(

Comment: @ScottCraner Got it... not sure what the problem was.... just typed it over and over until it worked

Answer (score 1):

Try a Scripting Dictionary approach.

```
Option Explicit

Sub reGroup()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Variant, dXYZs As Object

    Set dXYZs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dXYZs.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        For i = 2 To .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            If dXYZs.exists(.Cells(i, "A").Value2) Then
                dXYZs.Item(.Cells(i, "A").Value2) = _
                  dXYZs.Item(.Cells(i, "A").Value2) & ChrW(8203) & .Cells(i, "B").Value2
            Else
                dXYZs.Item(UCase(.Cells(i, "A").Value2)) = .Cells(i, "B").Value2
            End If
        Next i

        i = 0
        For Each k In dXYZs.keys
            .Cells(1, 4 + i) = k
            .Cells(2, 4 + i).Resize(UBound(Split(dXYZs.Item(k), ChrW(8203))) + 1) = _
                Application.Transpose(Split(dXYZs.Item(k), ChrW(8203)))
            i = i + 1
        Next k

    End With
End Sub
```

[image: scipting_dictionary]